How to allow layer 3 traffic to go from one zone into another zone in firewalld in RHEL 9?
I have reviewed the related documents and manual such as the https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewalld.policies.html but cannot find the answer... Could you guys please help. Thanks!
